# How to filter data after GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

There is this LIBRARY relational database. The relations are:

- BOOK (BookID, Title, PublisherName)
- BOOK_AUTHORS (BookID, AuthorName)
- PUBLISHER (Name, Address, Phone)
- BOOK_COPIES (BookID, BranchID, NumberOfCopies)
- BOOK_LOANS (BookID, BranchID, CardNumber, DateOut, DueDate)
- LIBRARY_BRANCH (BranchID, BranchName, Address)
- BORROWER (CardNumber, Name, Address, Phone)

Question: Retrieve all book titles that are available in “Sharpstown” branch but not in “Morristown” branch.

I wrote this query for the above question, but I'm not able to figure out how to do it simulataneously for both cases as some books might be available in all branches. Please help.

````
```sql
SELECT BOOK.Title
FROM BOOK_COPIES
JOIN LIBRARY_BRANCH
    ON LIBRARY_BRANCH.BranchID = BOOK_COPIES.BranchID
JOIN BOOK
    ON BOOK.BookID = BOOK_COPIES.BookID
GROUP BY BOOK.BookID
HAVING LIBRARY_BRANCH.BranchName = 'Sharpstown' 
```
````

Comment: Sample data and desired results will help, see [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Tip - this is a use-case for `not exists`

Comment: I don't have any sample data or else I would have tested the answers based on that.

Answer (score -1):

Use EXCEPT

```
  SELECT DISTINCT BOOK.Title
        FROM BOOK_COPIES
        JOIN LIBRARY_BRANCH
            ON LIBRARY_BRANCH.BranchID = BOOK_COPIES.BranchID
        JOIN BOOK
            ON BOOK.BookID = BOOK_COPIES.BookID
        WHERE LIBRARY_BRANCH.BranchName = 'Sharpstown' 
    EXCEPT 
      SELECT DISTINCT BOOK.Title
        FROM BOOK_COPIES
        JOIN LIBRARY_BRANCH
            ON LIBRARY_BRANCH.BranchID = BOOK_COPIES.BranchID
        JOIN BOOK
            ON BOOK.BookID = BOOK_COPIES.BookID
        WHERE LIBRARY_BRANCH.BranchName = 'Morristown'
```

Not the answer - see comment

No need to group, just 2 where and distinct to avoid duplicates

```
SELECT DISTINCT BOOK.Title
FROM BOOK_COPIES
JOIN LIBRARY_BRANCH
    ON LIBRARY_BRANCH.BranchID = BOOK_COPIES.BranchID
JOIN BOOK
    ON BOOK.BookID = BOOK_COPIES.BookID
WHERE LIBRARY_BRANCH.BranchName = 'Sharpstown' AND NOT LIBRARY_BRANCH.BranchName = 'Morristown'
```

Comment: NOT LIBRARY_BRANCH.BranchName = 'Morristown' will still return all matches from Sharpstown.  You need a NOT IN subquery.

Comment: Right I misunderstood the question .

Comment: @Taemyr I dont't know if I have to delete my answer ... that means delete your good comment?

Comment: You should be able to edit the answer.  So just change the criteria to a subquery rather than a equals check.

Comment: answer corrected, I let my previous one to be linked to your comment. Thanks @Taemyr

Comment: Initially I thougt this way only, but then I wanted to solve it using just one query and no subqueries. Let me know, if this can be solved by just one SELECT?

Comment: Not directly, you have to use except or a subquery as @Taemyr wrote, but it"s always 2 select. An other way should be to populate criterias from trgiggers and select on these calculated fields.

Comment: If something equals one , then, by definition, it doesn't equal two.

Comment: depends of the defintion :-) really easy to make one = two it IT

Comment: @Stawberry if you are the one who downvote, explain and give a better solution, it should be more consructive ...